# How would I add something to a number over and over again in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to add numbers in python. I know that it would be `x + 3` when you are adding it, but when I try to do it with the program I am writing, it doesn't work out how I want it to be!
Here is the code:

```
x = 0 

list = []

for i in range (1,100):
  y = x + 3 
  list.append(y)
print (list)
```

and the output we get is :

```
[3,3,3,3,3,3...]
```

When I want it to be:

```
[3,6,9,12,15]
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the result back to `x` so that it accumulates the values. You keep adding to the original value of `x`, since `x` never changes.

```
x = 0
l = []
for i in range(1, 100):
    x += 3
    l.append(x)

print(l)
```

BTW, don't use `list` as the name of a variable. It's the name of a Python built-in function.

Answer (score 0):

`x` is always 0, so you keep running `y = 0 + 3`, then adding that to the list

You dont need a `y` variable at all, you can run this in your loop

```
x += 3
lst.append(x)
```

Or, maybe simpler

```
lst = [3*x for x in range(1, 100)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your not increasing or incrementing the variable x. So after the statement list.append(y), in a new line, add x+=3

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:
you are not updating the `x` so you keep adding the original`x` value. so `x` have to be updated. but since you have y you can do this.

```
y = 0
mylist = []
for i in range (1,100):
  y += 3
  mylist.append(y)
print (mylist)
```

or do this you can just update the x value, then it works.

```
x = 0
mylist = []
for i in range (1,100):
  y = x + 3
  x += 3 #update the x variable
  mylist.append(y)
print (mylist)
```

And don't use `list` as the name of a variable. It's the name of a Python built-in function. In python so use another word like `mylist` or something.

Answer (score 0):

this will help

```
x = 0 

lst = []

for i in range (1,100):
    y = x+i*3
    lst.append(y) 
print(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the variable x,

Change the line `y=x+3` to `y=i*3`

In your script you are not redefining the value of x each time so you are doing 0+3 countless times. I is the index of the loop so will increase after each iteration, allowing you to have an increasing value in the list output

Answer (score 0):

You can write it in one line like this:

```
[x for x in range(1, 100) if x % 3 == 0]
```

or:

```
[x*3 for x in range(1, 100)]
```